# Detecting form changes using jQuery when the form changes themselves were triggered by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, jquery-events

I have a list of radio buttons that I can toggle "yes" or "no" to using Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select-all').click(function(){
        $('#notifications .notif-radio').each(function(){
            $('input[type="radio"]', this).eq(0).attr('checked', true);
            $('input[type="radio"]', this).eq(1).attr('checked', false);
        });
    });
    $('#deselect-all').click(function(){
        $('#notifications .notif-radio').each(function(){
            $('input[type="radio"]', this).eq(0).attr('checked', false);
            $('input[type="radio"]', this).eq(1).attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
});
```

this works just fine.  Now I have a separate piece of code that detects when a user has changed something,  and asks them if they want to leave the page.

```
var stay_on_page;

window.onbeforeunload = confirm_exit;

$('.container form input[TYPE="SUBMIT"]').click(function(){
    stay_on_page = false;
});

$('#wrapper #content .container.edit-user form').change(function(){
    stay_on_page = true;
});

function confirm_exit()
{
    if(stay_on_page){ return "Are you sure you want to navigate away without saving changes?"; }
}
```

The problem is that if the user uses the first piece of functionality to toggle all radio buttons one way or another.  The JS detecting form changes doesn't see that the form was changed.  I have tried using `.live`, but to no avail.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this by adding change() (or whatever's appropriate, click() in your case I suppose) event handlers which set either a visible or hidden field value, then check that value as part of your onbeforeunload function.

So, my on before unload looks like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      if ($('#dirtymark').length) {
           return "You have unsaved changes.";
      }
};
```

And, or course, dirtymark is added to the page (a red asterisk near the Save button), when the page becomes dirty.

Comment: i just added   window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Are you sure you want to navigate away without saving changes?"; }  right below the click functions